# Adding text to function and separating values

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me how I can add text to my output? I tried to do `print('The cpt/stuff pets folder contains the following:' +(os.listdir('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets'))` and I got an error so I'm not sure how to go about.

Also can anyone tell me how I can separate the two values on separate lines, its joining them together

`print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dognames.txt')), end='') print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dogs.jpg')), end='')`

```
    print(os.listdir('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff'))
print(os.listdir('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/cars'))
print(os.listdir('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets'))
print('The Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats folder contains the following:')
print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats', 'catnames.txt')), end='')
print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats', 'cats.jpg')), end='')
print('The Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs folder contains the following:')
print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dognames.txt')), end='')
print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs', 'dogs.jpg')), end='')
```

Comment: "and I got an error..." It would really help if you showed us the exact error, instead of just vaguely saying that you got an error.

Comment: @John TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: Don't use `+` to combine the two items in the print statement.  Use a comma instead.  `print('the directory contains:', os.listdir(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. 1 You can use str.format() for that:

```py
print(f"The cpt/stuff pets folder contains the following: {os.listdir('/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets')}")
```

No. 2 don't use `print(end="")`. If you want a newline every print, just use `print(value)`. `end=""` removes the newline. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: I tried No. 1 and this is the error I got TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str I tried adjusting it and it kept giving me the same error and eventually dropped to the next line

Comment: Thank you, glad to be here and excited for the new stuff I'll learn!

Comment: @raelyn I edited it. Try now. You shouldn't get that because format converts the list to string.

Comment: also I just tried No.2 and when I remove them I get 'Invalid Syntax'

Comment: I made a typo - again

Comment: I just tried the updated and this is the new error I got , EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @raelyn Are you sure you copy/pasted everything?

Comment: @raelyn You can mark the answer as correct and answered with the tick mark

Comment: would I go ahead and do that if I'm still have trouble with No.2

Comment: @raelyn Just print normally `print(value)`. That's what I said.